# How to do distortion on a topoJSON mesh

Tags: d3.js, topojson, fisheye

I'm working on a variation of a topojson map using fisheye distortion. While I have the topojson feature and datapoints apply the behavior, I can't seem to get it working for the mesh.

This is my code:

```
countries.attr('d', path);
      circles
        .attr('cx', function(d) { return set_projection(d.coordinates)[0]; })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return set_projection(d.coordinates)[1]; })
```

Another variation I've tried is:

```
  var line = d3.line();
  countries.attr("d", function(d) { 
  return line(d.coordinates.map(fisheye));
```

Both of them aren't working even though I've tried to apply the fisheye effect I've used for the feature and datapoints which retrieves the x and y. I'm assuming it's a different process but I'm stumped a bit. Can anyone help?

Comment: We'd need to have more of your code to understand what's your exact issue.

Comment: Sure thing, I have my code in here: https://codepen.io/qwirkyrabbit/pen/yjomwq